# Issue with delete button in a UITableView behind a custom UIView

Tags: ios, xcode

I am deleting a cell in a UITableView which has a UIImage view. When I swipe to delete the delete button is behind the UIView and it would look much better if the UIView was behind the delete button. Is there a way I can set the layer preference of the button to be on top?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

    [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];



    //Deletes view from cell
    for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {

        if (subview != self.tableView) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
[self performFetch];


}
```

Comment: What about the code you write? You want to hide your UIImageView?

Comment: I am not sure about hiding it but I want the delete button to be on top. I suppose hiding what's behind the button would be okay but you would need to unhide it if the user decides not to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have put your subviews (including your UIImageView) directly in the subview of the cell instead of the contentView.

Try adding them to the contentView instead.

Did you subclass your cell and added the view in the init method? Then use:

```
[[self contentView] addSubview:myImageView];
```

Didn't you subclass the cell and did you added the UIImageView in your ViewController?

```
[[cell contentView] addSubview:myImageView];
```

This will cause the contentView including your image to shrink when the deletebutton is shown.

If you really want to put it behind the button, try moving it to the back somewhere.

```
[self sendSubviewToBack:myImageView];
```